# Difference between background and concurrent garbage collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, .net-4.0

I read that with .NET Framework 4 the current garbage collection implementation is replaced:

> The .NET Framework 4 provides
>   background garbage collection. This
>   feature replaces concurrent garbage
>   collection in previous versions and
>   provides better performance.

At [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) there is an explanation how it works but I am not sure I understood it.

In practical world application what is the benefit of this new GC implementation? Is it a feature that could be use to push for a transition from 3.5 or previous to 4.0?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Here, Microsoft uses the names "concurrent" and "background" to describe two versions of the GC it uses in .NET. In the .NET world, the "background collector" is an enhancement over the "concurrent collector" in that it has less restrictions on what application threads can do while the collector is running.

A basic GC uses a "stop-the-world" strategy: applicative threads allocate memory blocks from a common heap. When the GC must run (e.g. too many blocks have been allocated, some cleanup is needed), *all* applicative (managed) threads stop. The last stopping thread runs the GC, and unblocks all the other threads when it has finished. A stop-the-world GC is simple to implement but induces pauses which can be perceptible at the user level.

Microsoft's "concurrent GC" is generational: it uses the stop-the-world strategy for only a limited part of the heap (what they call "generations 0 and 1"). Since that part remains small, pauses remain short (e.g. below 50ms), so that the user will not notice them. The rest of the heap is collected with a dedicated GC thread, which can run *concurrently* with the applicative threads (hence the name).

The concurrent GC has some limitations. Namely, there are moments when the GC thread must assume a somewhat exclusive control of the heap. During such times, applicative threads may allocate blocks only from small thread-specific areas. Threads which have bigger needs will soon stumble upon the main heap, which, at that time, is locked by the GC thread. The allocating thread must then block until the GC thread has finished its lock-the-heap phase. This again induces pauses. Less pauses than with a stop-the-world GC, and these pauses do not affect all threads. Yet pauses nonetheless.

The "background GC" is an enhanced GC in which the GC thread needs not lock the heap. This removes the extra pauses described in the previous paragraph; only remain the limited pauses when the young generations are collected (what Microsoft calls "a foreground collection").

**Note:** there are "hidden costs" with the concurrent GC and the background GC. For these GC to operate properly, memory accesses from applicative threads must be done in some very specific ways, which have a slight impact on performance. Also, the GC thread may have an adverse effect on cache memory, thus indirectly degrading performance. For a purely computational task with no need for user interaction, a stop-the-world collector may, *on average*, yield somewhat better performance (e.g. a twenty-hours-long computation will complete in nineteen hours). But this is an edge case, and in most situations the concurrent and background GC are better.

Comment: good explanation.. however it would be more appropriate if you stick to mainstream terminology. managed threads/code etc. Applicative? whats that?

Comment: Applicative threads are threads which run the code that the programmer writes (as opposed to hidden management threads, if there are any). "Managed" threads are threads which run managed code (i.e. not code which is written in C or C++). This _is_ mainstream terminology.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the real world explanation without slur and overinflated feeling of self-importance:

> In concurrent GC you were allowed to allocate while in a GC, but you are **not** allowed to start another GC while in a GC. This in turn means that the maximum you are allowed to allocate while in a GC is whatever space you have **left on one segment** (currently 16 MB in workstation mode) minus anything that is already allocated there).
>
> The difference in Background mode is that you **are allowed** to start a new GC (gen 0+1) while in a full background GC, and this **allows you to even create a new segment** to allocate in if necessary.  In short, the blocking that could occur before when you allocated all you could in one segment won’t happen anymore.

From Tess da Man! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/05/29/background-garbage-collection-in-clr-4-0.aspx

Comment: What operations are done by the GC, while the non-GC threads are running? If a non-GC thread tries to write a member of an object while the GC thread is moving it, what happens? If a reference to an object is created while the GC thread is moving it, what happens? What is simple to do in parallel is zeroing the memory that was used by the freed or moved objects. Is it just a marketing hype, and all is done in parallel is memset(ptr, 0, freedSize)?

Comment: I've found this after commenting:
"CLR starts background collection and resumes all managed threads.
Background thread marks all reachable objects in memory and suspends application threads for sweep or compact phase."
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/understanding-different-gc-modes-with-concurrency-visualizer/

Answer (score 1):

The primary benefit will be fewer application freezes due to garbage collection, which in itself could be considered a significant improvement. For most apps this difference will not be noticeable unless you have a HUGE number of long-lived objects in memory.

This change also makes .NET slightly more viable for building timing-sensitive apps (where response times are important). The extreme example are car airbags - you don't want your software to be busy doing garbage collection when they need to be inflated. The changes in 4.0 reduce the number and length of freezes due to GCing but does not remove them entirely.