# Reclaiming memory in a multithreaded environment - parallel tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, task

I am currently developing a small simulation utility, using the Task Parallel Library to improve the speed at which results are produced. The simulation itself is a long, cpu intensive job which is essentially made up of thousands of smaller jobs running a simulation with different variables.

However, the resources used by each task are not released until everything has completed, leading to memory leaks and out of memory exceptions if enough variables are used. Forcing a GC at the end of each task releases resources, but my understanding is that this needs to interrupt all threads to execute, and as such results in close to single thread performance!

How can I release resources during long operations like this?

By 'resources' in this context I'm referring to arrays of doubles... just a lot of them.

```
public List<AnalysisTask> Questions; //Each variable combination is added as a Q

//Create a task for each simulation
Task<SimulationResults>[] tasks = new Task<SimulationResults>[Questions.Count]; 
foreach(var q in Questions)
{
    AnalysisTask temp = q
    tasks[taskCount] = Task.Factory.StartNew((t) =>
             {
                var result = EvaluateRules(temp);
                if(reults.Value > Leader[0].Value)
                    Leader[0] = result;
                else
                {
                    result.Dispose();
                    //This releases resources but interrupts threads
                    //GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced); 
                    return null;
                }
                return result;

             }
}

//Completion task
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, (ant) =>
       {
          DoSomethingWithAnswer(Leader[0]);
       }
```

Perhaps I've taken the wrong approach in setting up the tasks? I'll be grateful for any advice or direction :)

Comment: The problem and symptoms were described in the second paragraph. All 3 answers given below were useful in improving the code, but the main issue was addressed by the accepted answer regarding references held by the array of tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation has a couple issues. One is that when an exchange is made with `Leader[0]`, the previous leader's reference is lost and it is never disposed. This could be the source of your memory leak. The second is that the comparison and assignment to `Leader[0]` are not done atomically. It is possible  to have this sequence of events: thread 1 compares to `Leader[0]` and gets true with a `result.Value` of 1, thread 2 compares to `Leader[0]` and gets true with a `result.Value` of 2, thread 2 writes to `Leader[0]`, thread 1 writes to `Leader[0]`. The result is that `Leader[0]` has a value of 1 when the maximal value was 2.

So if we properly dispose of references you might not need to force garbage collection. The code below fixes those issues by taking out a lock when modifying `Leader` and storing a reference to the previous `Leader[0]`. Then either the unused result or previous leader is disposed. Presumably `EvaluateRules` will take some time so there shouldn't be much lock contention.

```
tasks[taskCount] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
        var result = EvaluateRules(temp);

        var toBeDisposed = result;
        lock(Leader) // should be locking on a private object
        {
           if (result.Value > Leader[0].Value)
           {
             toBeDisposed = Leader[0];
             Leader[0] = result;
           }
        }

        toBeDisposed.Dispose();       

     });
```

Also, do you need to be returning `result` from each task? You seem to only need `Leader[0]` for your continuation task. By returning `result` you are storing a reference that cannot be gc'd until the tasks themselves are gc'd.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection doesn't stop your entire process. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583644/difference-between-background-and-concurrent-garbage-collection) for more information.

If you must invoke a GC (or your process dies), and if a GC really does hurt your performance (it's unlikely you perform a GC *all the time*), you can always break your simulation into several processes (don't use a process per thread, of course, but every X threads can belong to one process).

I have to admit, though, that you're probably doing something wrong with your memory management, but you need to provide more information.

Comment: Following your comment and link I noticed a GC interrupt described as "pauses remain short (e.g. below 50ms)"... each individual simulation takes perhaps 2ms to execute so calling the collect each time explained why it had such an impact. I had only really added the call as a test in identifying the leak, but calling it every x tasks helps.

Perhaps not yet pooling the arrays as Martin James has suggested would count as doing something wrong with memory management.

Comment: Try processing more than one simulation in each task.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are contant size, or a maximum size can be defined, or a set of size range can be defined, you could maybe create a pool of these arrays at startup or build up a pool of lists of arrays of sizes during the run. Then there would be no need to deallocate the arrays - just repool them for re-use later.  An array of BlockingCollection[sizeRange] queues would do as the pool.

Comment: I've limited the array size by introducing a cyclic array, so having a pool of arrays looks to be a viable solution... I'll have a look in to this!

Comment: If there is an array of pools of different sizes, it's easiest if each dataArray object has a reference to its own pool as a private data member. That way, you only have to call a 'release()' method on any dataArray to have it requeue itself to its correct pool.  It's also worthwhile, while debugging anyway, to include a check in the 'requeue(thisData)' method of the pool that 'thisData' is not already in the pool.  A double-release eventually results in two different threads popping the same dataArray from the pool with disastrous consequences - I did this today on my embedded project:(