# How do concurrent, background and server garbage collection differ in C#?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am aware of the config setting, [`<gcConcurrent>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element), but the documentation and articles I have read refer to background garbage collection with separate threads as well as concurrency. The documentation also talks about multiple threads in server mode. Can someone clarify the differences? I am trying to get an understanding of what results from changing `<gcConcurrent`> setting in config and how that fits in with also possibly changing the setting `<gcServer>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between background and concurrent garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583644/difference-between-background-and-concurrent-garbage-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background GC**

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, concurrent garbage collection is replaced by background garbage collection. The terms concurrent and background are used interchangeably in the .NET Framework documentation. [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element)

So we can say that **background** GC uses a dedicated thread to garbage collect **concurrently**  (that is, in parallel) with your application's threads. This concurrent collection only occurs in generation 2 (0 and 1 are fast).

**Workstation GC**

This is the default and is forced in single processor environments.

Background GC is always enabled.

**Server GC**

GC will create a thread for garbage collection per logical processor and will create separate object heaps for each (your code will be unaware of this), which allows for faster parallel/concurrent GC.

You can enable server GC in your .config file with:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Background GC is enabled by default but can be disabled in configuration like so:

```
…
<gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
…
```

And yes, background GC enabled, as well as Server mode, will result in 2 threads per logical processor solely for GC but this is not a big concern as they are kept in a suspended state outside of GC operations.